# XHR response keeps getting cancelled

Tags: python, api, xmlhttprequest, response

**I have an HTML form:**

```
<form id="form_id" method="post">
  <label>First Name :</label>
  
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="Adam">
  <label>Last Name :</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="Albert">
  
  <input type="submit" name="create_customer" id="btn_next" value="Next" onclick="next(btn_next.name)">
</form>
```

**My JavaScript for the onclick action:**

```
function next(contextID) {
console.log("I am in ");
  document.getElementById('form_id').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
   console.log("executed default ");
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var params = {"fname": fname, "lname": lname, "contextID": contextID}
    console.log("PRINT -> value of params: "+ JSON.stringify(params))

    document.getElementById("form_id").submit(); //form submission

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX/routecontrol";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
     console.log("calling API ");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    console.log("Response is "+xhr.status);
 });
}
```

**My flask API:**

```
@app.route('/routecontrol', methods=['POST'])
#@cross_origin(origin='*')
def post():
    
    content = request.data
    dict_str = content.decode("UTF-8")
    dataObj = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
   
    nextRoute = dataObj['contextID']
    
    if nextRoute == "create_customer":

        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE' }
        url = 'http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX/createCustomer'
        
        response = requests.post(url, data=request.data, headers=headers)
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'

        print("headers", response.headers)
        print("headers", response.status_code)
        print("headers", response.text)
        print("this is the return ", response.content)
    
    return response
```

The API's 'response' has the data (I printed it out in the Flask log) but it never makes it back to my javascript function. I keep getting 'XHR cancelled' error in DevTools. The console logging the xhr.status in my JavaScript shows 0. I am not sure what might be causing this as I cannot debug it any deeper in DevTools. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone ever finding this because of a similar problem, the solution to this was to change the authentication required flag from true to false in my xhr.open call. I was working entirely off of my laptop and the base Flask web server that comes out of the box with Flask.